# How to quicky insert and modify UUID field in MySQL and IntelliJ database service?

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, uuid

I am struggling with inserting and modifying UUID field in MySQL. I use UUID for id and foreign key in Spring JPA and MySQL. I see that in MySQL, they are stored as binary(16). When I insert new value or update value directly from Workbench table or IntelliJ database service, it is impossible. IntelliJ tells me that data too long and the format of column change from UUID to Text.
For example:[image]

I know that I can insert through Spring Boot service or query but it is too slow. How can I directly change these values in table like this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE (your_table_name);; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "(your_table_name)";